# Redirect instead update Ajax MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is part of .cshtml where update must occurs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewMessage",new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "messages"}))
{

    @Html.TextBox("Enter Message");
    <input type="submit" />

   <div id="messages">      
   </div>     
}
```

here is action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewMessage(UserMessage message)
    {
        message.TimePost = DateTime.Now;
        message.Author = "author";
        message.Message = "message";

        return PartialView("NewMessage",message);
    }
```

Why instead of update I redirected to "NewMessage" action ?
Should I include any other scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing some scripts...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/Js/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/Js/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/Js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/Js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```